# Plug.Conn.assign not working when called from a Pipeline Plug

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm following the [Phoenix Guide on Plugs](http://www.phoenixframework.org/v0.13.1/docs/understanding-plug) to create my own `Module Plug` that loads the current user from session. The `@user` is not being assigned when the Plug Module is used, but works fine when I call it as a private function within `router.ex`.

This is my `web/router`:

```
defmodule MyApp.Router do
  use MyApp.Web, :router

  pipeline :browser do
    plug :accepts, ["html"]
    plug :fetch_session
    plug :fetch_flash
    plug :protect_from_forgery
    plug MyApp.Plugs.User
  end

  # Scopes and Routes...

end
```

This is my Module (in `web/plugs/user.ex`):

```
defmodule MyApp.Plugs.User do
  import Plug.Conn

  def init(default), do: default

  def call(conn, default) do
    user = %{
      id:       get_session(conn, :user_id),
      username: get_session(conn, :username)
    }

    assign(conn, :user, user)

    IO.inspect conn
  end
end
```

I tried inspecting it to see if it really was being assigned, but it wasn't:

```
%Plug.Conn{adapter: {Plug.Adapters.Cowboy.Conn, :...}, assigns: %{},
 before_send: [#Function<1.75757453/1 in Plug.CSRFProtection.call/2>,
  #Function<1.30521811/1 in Phoenix.Controller.fetch_flash/2>,
  #Function<0.39713025/1 in Plug.Session.before_send/2>,
  #Function<1.7608073/1 in Plug.Logger.call/2>,
  #Function<0.72065156/1 in Phoenix.LiveReloader.before_send_inject_reloader/1>],
 body_params: %{},
 cookies: ....
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`Plug.Conn.assign` returns a modified connection. Since all data in Elixir is immutable it's not possible to modify the old one. In your case you're throwing away the result of `assign` and conn still points to the old connection. You probably want something like:

```
conn = assign(conn, :user, user)
```

This will rebind the `conn` variable to point to the modified connection structure. Of course it would also work if `assign(conn, :user, user)` would be the last expression in your function since its result would be returned.

Comment: I see... I guess I should get my Elixir basics right before I move on to Phoenix.

Comment: Also note that `IO.inspect` returns the value it inspects, so `assign(conn, :user, user) |> IO.inspect` would also have worked